how to find the resource using API?
When I disable certificatemanager.googleapis.com, I got the error:

Error disabling service "certificatemanager.googleapis.com" for project "prj1": Error waiting for api to disable: Error code 9, message: [Error in service 'certificatemanager.googleapis.com': Not ready to deactivate the service on this project; ensure there are no more resources managed by this service.

But I listed all possible resources as follows, with the location or not:
  gcloud certificate-manager certificates list --location=us-west1 
  gcloud certificate-manager dns-authorizations list --location=us-west1
  gcloud certificate-manager issuance-configs list --location=us-west1
  gcloud certificate-manager maps list --location=us-west1
  gcloud certificate-manager operations list --location=us-west1
  gcloud certificate-manager trust-configs list --location=us-west1
  gcloud certificate-manager maps entries list --location=us-west1

The only result is operations, which can't be deleted.
How to find the resources which using the API?

You can try below commands to list all certificates list:
gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader false

gcloud compute ssl-certificates  list --location=global --project=my-project

gcloud certificate-manager certificates list --location=global --project=my-project

You also need to check cloud logging to further verify the issue you're encountering
